# How to add clients logo on bottom Tab Bar

Tags: react-native

i am creating an android based mobile app using react native. I want to add a logo on my bottom tab. The tab bar also contains 4 tabs. I need to display a logo on left corner of my device. Logo is not a clickable one, just an image.

Comment: You need to add more content... this can be done in many ways, show us some code and some things that you've tried

Comment: i used to add logo on top of the page, but i need that logo on bottom of the page, near by my bottom tab bar.    static navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false,
     // title: 'aaaa',
      headerLeft: (
        <View style={{width:'100%'}}>
        <Image source ={require('aaa.png'')} style={{width:200,height:55}} resizeMode="contain"/>
        </View>
      ),
     
  }; i did this method for add logo on top of the age.bu i need this same thing on my tab bar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

For React Navigation 5.
You can show custom BottomTabBar with tabBar options.

1. Define Tab stack

```html
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <BottomTabBar {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Tab1" component={Screen3} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Tab2" component={Screen2} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Tab3" component={Screen2} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Tab4" component={Screen2} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

2. Create Custom BottomTabBar

```html
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text,Image,Platform,TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const BottomTabBar = ({state, navigation, ...props}) => {
  const {routes = [], index: activeIndex} = state;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={require('../../assets/logo.png')}
        style={styles.imageIcon}
      />
      <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
        {routes.map((it, index) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.jumpTo(it.name);
              }}
              style={[
                styles.tabButton,
                {
                  borderBottomWidth: activeIndex === index ? 1 : 0,
                },
              ]}>
              <Text>{it.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
export default BottomTabBar;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabButton: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
  },
  tabContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
  },
  imageIcon: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 64,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    paddingBottom: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 15 : 0,
  },
});
```

3. ScreenShot
   [image]